# Adding an item to a cursor MeteorJS

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here is my code right now:

```
Template.home.helpers({
    categories: function(){
         // Categories is a collection defined earlier
         return Categories.find();
    },
});
        var categories = Categories.find();
        /**
        categories.append({
            name: "All",
            icon: "home"
        });
        */
        return categories;
    },
```

It is just returning all the categories from the database I am using. I want to make an aggregate category. For example, saw I have 2 categories:

```
[
{
  name: "Link",
  views: 5
},
{
  name: "Time",
  views: 10,
}]
```

Say I want a 3rd category:

```
{
  name: "All",
  views: 15 // this is from 10 + 5
}
```

How would I go about adding that to the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a cursor, a helper can also return an array (or a single value). Therefore, you can solve your problem by fetching all of the existing categories into an array, modifying it with the desired data, and returning the modified array. Here is an example implementation:

```js
Template.home.helpers({
  categories: function() {
    // fetch all of the categories into an array
    var cats = Categories.find().fetch();

    // compute the total views for all categories
    var totalViews = _.reduce(cats, function(memo, cat) {
      return memo + cat.views;
    }, 0);

    // add a new 'category' with the total views
    cats.push({name: 'All', views: totalViews});

    // return the array of modified categories
    return cats;
  }
});
```